Держать ли 1 соединение или открывать/закрывать под каждый запрос? mongo db + motor
Держать ли 1 соединение или открывать/закрывать под каждый запрос?
mongo db  + motor
Пишу api на flask. Использую mongo db и асинк драйвер motor
Есть ли смысл при обработке запросов открывать и закрывать соединения под каждый отдельный запрос? или же стоит держать одно соединение на все приложение? какие преимущества у каждого способа?
Отдельные коннекты
@SYSTEM.route('/ping')
def ping():
    cluster = create_connection()
    # работа с бд
    close_connection(cluster)
    return {
        'result': 'ok'
    }

Общий коннект
cluster = create_connection()

@SYSTEM.route('/ping')
def ping():
    #работа с база данных
    return {
        'result': 'ok'
    }


Самым лучшим вариантом будет рассмотреть возможность использование пулов соединений. Такой вариант окажется самым производительным и эффективным.
Создание и закрытие соединений потребляет много времени и ресурсов. Но если у вас используется много одновременных запросов, то имеет смысл открывать и закрывать соединения под каждый запрос.

Почему? С ваших слов: "Создание и закрытие соединений потребляет много времени и ресурсов"
Тогда же наоборот стоит использовать одно соединение при большом кол-ве запросов, не так ли?

Нельзя использовать одно соединение для большого количества запросов из-за возможных проблем с производительностью, будут возникать просадки по скорости и перегрузки.
А вот пул соединений как раз решает эту проблему, позволяя наиболее эффективным образом распределять нагрузку между несколькими соединениями и переиспользовать их в будущем.
